# React addEventListener not working with select2 events

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, reactjs, jquery-select2

Here is the situation: I have a Ruby on Rails site that has a view that uses select2 and ajax to populate a select list. I am in the process of rewriting the view to use React.js. When a user selects an option from the select list I need to update the state of the parent component but React does not seem to want to listen to select2 events.

This is my react component so far, but it fails to recognize the `select2:select` event:

```
class PhonePrompts extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      clientId: this.props.clientId
    };

    this.handleClientChange = this.handleClientChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleClientChange(event) {
    console.log("fired");
    // this.handleClientChange($('.inquiry-client-ajax').select2("val"));
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.refs.clientSelect);
    $(this.refs.clientSelect).select2({
      ajax: {
        url: '/tasks/inquiry-client-ajax',
        dataType: 'json',
        delay: 250,
        data: function(params) {
          return {
            q: params.term
          };
        },
        processResults: function(data) {
          return {
            results: data
          };
        },
        cache: true
      },
      minimumInputLength: 3,
      placeholder: 'Client...'
    });
    this.refs.clientSelect.addEventListener("select2:select", this.handleClientChange);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.refs.clientSelect.removeEventListener("select2:select", this.handleClientChange);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form >
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div className="form-group">
              <select ref='clientSelect' className="form-control inquiry-client-ajax" value={this.props.clientId} />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <input className="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Interest..." />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <input className="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Trip..." />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

However, when I add a basic coffeescript event listener to the view, it works fine:

```
$('.inquiry-client-ajax').on 'select2:select', (evt) ->
  console.log('Client is now: ' + $('.inquiry-client-ajax').select2("val"))
  return
```

Has anybody run into this problem before?

Comment: firstly using refs changed in the newer versions of react. You have to do something along these lines

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Comment: ok, good to know thanks! Unfortunately, now I do not know how to refer to that DOM node to add an event listener.